# Сортировка всех столбцов в DataFrame не указывая явно наименования столбцов

Tags: python, pandas, сортировка, dataframe, numpy

Начал изучать pandas и столкнулся с наверное простой проблемой. У меня есть датафрейм  в виде матрицы чисел 150х4 загруженный из файла. Я хочу отсортировать в нём все столбцы по возрастанию. Использую функцию sort_values(), но она сортирует либо первый столбец, либо нужно указывать название каждого столбца в атрибутах функции. А если я не знаю названия столбцов, как мне сказать функции, что я хочу отсортировать все?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('iris.txt', sep=",", header = None)
print(data.sort_values(by=0))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [86]: data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(10,4)))

In [87]: data
Out[87]:
     0    1    2    3
0  487  487  649  808
1   72   72  826  991
2  449  912  316  847
3  592  979  365  934
4  451  614  268  439
5  256  920   63   51
6   36  957   16  493
7  734  958  432  287
8  981  760  396  168
9  826  394  289  562

In [88]: data.sort_values(df.columns.tolist())
Out[88]:
     0    1    2    3
6   36  957   16  493
1   72   72  826  991
5  256  920   63   51
2  449  912  316  847
4  451  614  268  439
0  487  487  649  808
3  592  979  365  934
7  734  958  432  287
9  826  394  289  562
8  981  760  396  168
```

---

Иногда возникает необходимость отсортировать все столбцы независимо друг от друга (с потерей целостности строк). Это можно сделать используя [numpy.sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
import numpy as np

In [102]: pd.DataFrame(np.sort(data, axis=0), columns=data.columns)
Out[102]:
     0    1    2    3
0   36   72   16   51
1   72  394   63  168
2  256  487  268  287
3  449  614  289  439
4  451  760  316  493
5  487  912  365  562
6  592  920  396  808
7  734  957  432  847
8  826  958  649  934
9  981  979  826  991
```

Comment: Подскажите, в чем принципиальное различие с моим ответом? Я сам только учусь работать с `pandas`, по этому возможно не знаю банальные вещи =)

Comment: @Viktorov, принципиального различия нет, скорее косметическое. `df.columns.tolist()` - чуть более "пандаистический" подход по сравнению с `list(data.columns)`, кстати `list(data)` - вернет тоже самое ;) Плюс всегда полезно показать как это работает на примере...

Answer (score 3):

Можно так попробовать:

```
data.sort_values(by=list(data.columns),axis=0)
```